# Rails form_tag :remote attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am trying to use rails `form_tag` to generate a form with `remote='true'`, but it keeps adding `data-remote='true'` instead!

Here is my view:

```
<%= form_tag( update_shipping_order_path(@order), method: :put, :remote => true) do %>
```

And here is the generated HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/orders/1012/update_shipping" data-remote="true" method="post" novalidate="no validate">
```

It is also adding `method='post'` instead of `put`.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Why don't you just tell me what's wrong instead of downvoting

Comment: Please refer to http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, Rails is not magic & has to work in the confines of both [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/DEFAULT.asp) & [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

This means when you use the many helpers in Rails, [such as the `form builder`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html), all of the attributes you pass will have to be "translated" to the front-end HTML somehow. And the way to do this is to [use `data` attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) in your HTML

It's just Rails' way of rendering the correct HTML & transferring the right data back & forth